# MathJax: Is it possible to highlight only specific elements and not the whole document?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, showdown

I am writing a blog with markdown-functionality, the lib I use is called `showdown.js`. But this markdown-lib doesn't support formula-rendering. So that's why I wonder, if it is possible, to let `MathJax` only render a given DOM-Element?
I know, that there is a lib, called `showdown-katex`, but considering that I use `Spring Boot` for my server, I am not able to include javascript-libs, installed with `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `elements` option in the `startup` section of your MathJax configuration ([documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/startup/startup.html):

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    elements: ['#id', '.class']
  }
};
</script>
```

where `id` is replaced by the ID of an element to typeset, or `class` is replaced by a class that selects the elements to typeset.  You can use any CSS selectors, this is just an example.